# Symfony2 Custom Form, Replace Attribute, Value and Theme

Tags: php, html, symfony

I'm new to Symfony. I've read the manual for Symfony and searched the web but still can't find example for this problem.

This is the "new.html.twig"

```
{% block content %}

{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block _sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama_widget %}
<div class="form-group">    
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
 {{ form_widget(form) }}
                   </div>
              </section>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the result :

```
<div class="form-group">    
    <div class="col-sm-10">     
        <div id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode">
            <div>
                <label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" class="required">Nama</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[nama]" required="required" maxlength="50" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_keterangan">Keterangan</label>
                <input type="text" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_keterangan" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[keterangan]" maxlength="250" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_aktif">Aktif</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_aktif" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[aktif]" value="1" />
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Default Here</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[nama]" required="required" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_keterangan">Keterangan</label>
    <input type="text" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_keterangan" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[keterangan]" maxlength="250" />
</div>
div>
    <label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_aktif">Aktif</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_aktif" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[aktif]" value="1" />
</div>
```

Conclusion :

1. How to make label `<label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Default Here</label>` inside my `<div class="form-group"></div>` but outside `<div class="col-sm-10"><div>`
2. How to replace a class and value in `<label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" class="required">Nama</label>` into this `<label for="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Default Here</label>`
3. How to add a class in `<input type="text" id="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode_nama" name="sifo_schoolbundle_mstperiode[nama]" required="required" maxlength="50" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony uses the following blocks for rendering
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

So you should define

```
{% block form_row %}
<div class="form-group">
  {% form_label(form) %}
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    {% form_widget(form) %}
    {% form_errors(form) %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And so on to satisfy your HTML.

Or try to use any of existing symfony bootstrap bundles.
E.g. this one https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle

Comment: I've try that too. But the result still same. '{{ form_label(form) }}' return label of form not label of my field (entity).

Comment: Because you calling `form_label` on top form.
For top form you should call `{{ form(form) }}`, then it will call `{{ form_row(form) }}` for each field, `form_row` will call `form_label` and `form_widget`, `form_widget` will call corresponding widget rendering function and so on.